# Dynamic entity property adjustment in OptaPlanner during pptimization process

Tags: java, optimization, optaplanner

I'm working on an OptaPlanner project for vehicle routing optimization, and I have a specific requirement. We are facing overconstrained planning problem, i.e. skip customer stops. We've decided to go with one plausible solution of adding virtual values to catch the unassigned entities as mentioned in the documentation. I want to automatically adjust the isVirtual property of certain BusStop entities in my domain based on the optimization process.

Here's a simplified version of my domain model:

```
public class BusStop {
    private boolean isVirtual;
    // Other properties and getters/setters
}
```

I want this change to be dynamic and influence the optimization process to improve the overall score, as if the isVirtual property was part of the score calculation.

Could anyone provide some guidance or an example of how I can achieve this behavior in OptaPlanner?

Work done till now: during the optimization process, when the total route distance of a Bus exceeds a certain threshold (e.g., 150,000 meters), I automatically set the isVirtual property of some BusStop entities to true in constraint provider implementation itself but that is being carried out to other solutions as well.

Comment: See [the issue for this](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/76) on Timefold (the continuation of OptaPlanner) too.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't make `isVirtual` a planning variable, that will explode the search space.

Instead, I 'd add a medium constraint (after switching to a HardMediumSoftLongScore) to penalize the number of assigned virtual vehicles.

That way, you don't have to deal with the fickle 150,000 meters thresholds etc.